# We normal scroll the page come in the next section should be going to top of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

We normal scroll the page come in the next section should be going to top of the page. No need single mouse wheel scroll.

```css
.bg1 {
 background-color: #C5876F;
 height: 1000px;
}
.bg2 {
 background-color: #7882BB;
 height: 1000px;
}
.bg3 {
 background-color: #8AC196;
 height: 900px;
}
.bg4 {
 background-color: #DD9698;
 height: 1000px;
}
h1 {
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 50px;
 margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="section1" class="bg1">
 <h1>Section 1</h1>
</section>

<section id="section2" class="bg2">
 <h1>Section 2</h1>
</section>
 
<section id="section3" class="bg3">
 <h1>Section 3</h1>
</section>
 
<section id="section4" class="bg4">
 <h1>Section 4</h1>
</section>
```

> We scroll the page come in the next section should be going to top of the page

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to scroll to next section at single mouse wheel event:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sections = $('.bg');
    var dir = 'up'; // wheel scroll direction
    var section = 0; // current section
    $(document.body).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
            dir = 'down';
        } else {
            dir = 'up';
        }
        // find currently visible section :
        section = -1;
        sections.each(function(i){
            if (section<0 && ($(this).offset().top >= $(window).scrollTop())) {
                section = i;
            }
        });
        if (dir == 'up' && section > 0) {
            section--;
        }
        if (dir == 'down' && section < sections.length) {
            section++;
        }
        if (section == sections.length) return;
        $('html,body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: sections.eq(section).offset().top
        }, 200);
        return false;
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('html,body').scrollTop(sections.eq(section).offset().top);
    });
});
```

```css
#section1 {
 background-color: #C5876F;
 height: 1000px;
}
#section2 {
 background-color: #7882BB;
 height: 1000px;
}
#section3 {
 background-color: #8AC196;
 height: 900px;
}
#section4 {
 background-color: #DD9698;
 height: 1000px;
}
h1 {
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 50px;
 margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="section1" class="bg">
 <h1>Section 1</h1>
</section>

<section id="section2" class="bg">
 <h1>Section 2</h1>
</section>
 
<section id="section3" class="bg">
 <h1>Section 3</h1>
</section>
 
<section id="section4" class="bg">
 <h1>Section 4</h1>
</section>
```